# Is it possible to use LMS in Screen Flows?

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, lightning-message-service

I wanted to ask whether there is a possibility to use **LMS - Lightning Message Service** on **Screen Flows** in order to enable communication between its components.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it's not automatic. Each component that you want to participate has to publish and subscribe to events.

You may be interested in having components respond to changed outputs from other components on the same screen. If that's the case, check out [Reactive Screens, a Flow feature that's now in pilot.](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/groups/0F94S000000kGWqSAM?tab=discussion&sort=LAST_MODIFIED_DATE_DESC)